# How to produce a sectional view of 3d-mesh by CGAL

Tags: c++, graphics, mesh, cgal, graph-visualization

I am running CGAL's 3d mesh examples and modifying them in my own way. But I want to have cut views of those generated meshes just like what [CGAL website](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#fig__figureliver_3d_image_mesh) displays, but CGAL doesn't seem to have given any suggestion of software or code examples to do so. Any ideas to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just write the mesh out to a file and use [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/). They have the *crinkle clip* feature you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for coming back late. I tried it today but paraview told me could not find a reader for *.mesh file produced by CGAL, and ask me to manually choose a reader. Could you tell me which one you chose?

Comment: Convert the file with [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) or install the meshio Paraview plugin (see readme).

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the polyhedron demo and run the tetrahedral mesh generator in there, it will provide you a cut plane that you can move around.

Comment: Hi, sorry for coming back late. I am new to CGAL. I guess you are referring to the polyhedron_cut_plane_3 function in polyhedron_cut_plane_3.h. But it looks like it can do nothing with c3t3 type object (which is exactly the type I have with my 3D mesh object)?